# Count number of columns with some values for each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this,
data:

```
Site code    Col1  Col2  Col3
A5252        24    53     NaN
A5636        36    NaN    NaN
A4366        NaN   NaN    NaN
A7578        42    785    24
```

And I want to count a number of columns with some value, but none NaN. 
Desired output:

```
 Site code   Col1  Col2  Col3  Count
    A5252     24    53     NaN    2
    A5636     36    NaN    NaN    1
    A4366     NaN   NaN    NaN    0
    A7578     42    785    24     3
```

Something oposite to this:
df = data.isnull().sum(axis=1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Need change [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) to [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html):

```
#if first columns is not index, set it
data = data.set_index('Site code')
data['Count'] = data.notnull().sum(axis=1)
```

Or use function [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

```
data = data.set_index('Site code')
data['Count'] = data.count(axis=1)
print (data)
           Col1   Col2  Col3  Count
Site code                          
A5252      24.0   53.0   NaN      2
A5636      36.0    NaN   NaN      1
A4366       NaN    NaN   NaN      0
A7578      42.0  785.0  24.0      3
```

Another solution with selecting columns by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (`Site code` is column, not `index`):

```
print (data.loc[:, 'Col1':])
   Col1   Col2  Col3
0  24.0   53.0   NaN
1  36.0    NaN   NaN
2   NaN    NaN   NaN
3  42.0  785.0  24.0

data['Count'] = data.loc[:, 'Col1':].count(axis=1)
print (data)
  Site code  Col1   Col2  Col3  Count
0     A5252  24.0   53.0   NaN      2
1     A5636  36.0    NaN   NaN      1
2     A4366   NaN    NaN   NaN      0
3     A7578  42.0  785.0  24.0      3
```

Another nice idea  from [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717137/count-number-of-columns-with-some-values-for-each-row-in-pandas/44717151?noredirect=1#comment76416920_44717151) - use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
data['Count'] = data.filter(regex="^Col").count(axis=1)
print (data)

  Site code  Col1   Col2  Col3  Count
0     A5252  24.0   53.0   NaN      2
1     A5636  36.0    NaN   NaN      1
2     A4366   NaN    NaN   NaN      0
3     A7578  42.0  785.0  24.0      3
```

Comment: Or a slight alternative to the last example in cases where the name of the columns is known but their order may not be: `df.filter(regex="^Col")`

Answer (score 2):

Simple use `notnull()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv")

df['count'] = df.notnull().sum(axis=1)

print(df)
```

Also to add a column to a dataframe just use:

```
df['new_column_name'] = newcolumn
```

output:

```
Site code   Col1  Col 2  Col3  count
    A5252     24    53     NaN    2
    A5636     36    NaN    NaN    1
    A4366     NaN   NaN    NaN    0
    A7578     42    785    24     3
```